# Paypal credit card payments integration problem

Tags: php, paypal

I got problem when I submit credit card information to paypal, It'll give me error like "There’s an error with this transaction. Please enter a country in the billing address." Though I send "COUNTRY" parameters in NVP string. Below is my NVP string.

Can anyone help me Please ? Thanks in advance.

```
$nvpstr="&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&IPADDRESS=$ip&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&
ACCT=$creditCardNumber&EXPDATE=".$padDateMonth.$expDateYear."&CVV2=$cvv2Number&
FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName&STREET=$address1&STREET2=$address2&CITYNAME=$city&
STATEORPROVINCE=$state&POSTALCODE=$zip&COUNTRY=$country&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyCode";
```

Help me.

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: have you `var_dump()`ed your `$country` to be sure it has a string inside?

Comment: Yes. I have echoed that string too.

Answer (score 2):

`METHOD=doDirectPayment

&VERSION=65.1

&PWD=1314384818

&USER=taruku_1314384782_biz_api1.smaotdatainc.net

&SIGNATURE=A7IZoLJTxfLBP8mJElBqhcYwz10QhhzhFE3ZJbQDUy5L140pQPdMoinR

&PAYMENTACTION=Sale

&AMT=1.00

&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa

&ACCT=4831623809779107

&EXPDATE=012012&CVV2=962

&FIRSTNAME=John

&LASTNAME=Doe

&STREET=1+Main+St

&CITY=San+Jose

&STATE=CA

&ZIP=95131

&COUNTRYCODE=US

&CURRENCYCODE=USD`

Match your string with this one..
I think "COUNTRY" should be "COUNTRYCODE"
also if problem exists match other address related parameters... :) will work fine..

Answer (score 1):

These are incorrect parameters. Use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET, PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRY, etc.
https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout

Note: PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ is optional. It's used for parallel payments. If you don't use that, just follow the docs and add PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ wherever it says so.